# "Свободный" vs. "вольный"

Tags: значения

What is the difference in meaning between "свобода" and "воля" and also between "свободный" and "вольный"?

Comment: By the way, there is third synonym: _вольность_, which is closer to _свобода_ than _воля_.

Comment: No, вольность or допустить вольность is "do something on your own", usually it's used in negative context. Воля and свобода is synonyms, but воля is also used as wish, for example The King's Wishes == Царская воля

Comment: @aknew, that too. But I did not talk about _допустить вольность_, but about _вольность_ as ‘freedom’ in general sense: _Чужой для всех, ничем не связан, / Я думал: вольность и покой / Замена счастью. Боже мой! [Пушкин]_, _Он вольность хочет проповедать! _[Грибоедов]_. It is not in use in modern colloquial speech of course.

Comment: There's also a word "волевой" (approximately "willed"), though it is not associated with freedom.

Comment: Wasn't "вольность" in "Он вольность хочет проповедать" also used in negative meaning? Anyway, in modern Russian "вольность" is certainly used in the expression "допустить вольность", and only "воля" can have such connotation. I'd say "свобода" has strong associations with expanse, large spaces, not being restricted or suppressed in any way. "Воля" is more about doing as you please and also not being in captivity — which provides a basis for uses in negative contexts because doing as you wish may not be good for others, depending on what you do exactly.

Comment: @Shady_arc Of course, Фамусов was talking about _вольность_ as about something negative, but that was only because he was a staunch anti-liberal :-). _Вольность_ per se had no such connotations. (Do no forget to use @-addressing, otherwise a person, who you are talking to, might read your comment only by accident).

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov "Вольность" per se in contemporary usage does not have any other meanings than taking liberties with something or someone, or maybe behaving too unconventional and against the rules. Negative connotations are not a necessity there.

Answer (score 3):

`свобода (свободный) и воля (вольный)` have [many meanings](http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/). And only few of them are synonymous. Let's take a look at those synonymous meanings by way of examples:

- `вольный/свободный народ/люди/жизнь`
- `вольный ветер` - I wouldn't use `свободный` here
- <strike>`вольная`</strike>/`свободная продажа, по` <strike>`вольным`</strike>/`свободным ценам`
- `волен/свободен поступать, как хочет`
- `слишком свободное/вольное поведение`
- `свободные движения, свободное дыхание, свободно говорить по-французски` - can't be replaced with `вольный` here

So the main difference to my mind is that `свобода` means that there are **barriers** and the subject is free from them. So usually we don't say `свободный ветер` because you can't possibly imagine barriers for a wind. But movements, breath, speech can be restricted and so you can be free from limitations.

Likewise `воля` has a hidden connotation that the subject **wants** something (that's his will and hence the freedom to do it). So a wind is free to go wherever it wants and we say `вольный` to add human features such as will, willfulness, playfulness to the wind. And we can't say `вольное дыхание` because we breath, move, speak a foreign language not [voluntarily](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/voluntarily) , at least not in the big sense. And will is attributable only to **humans**.

One other thing worth mentioning here in this comparison is that `воля, вольный` are less frequent words. Don't use them unless you really know what you want to say. `свободный ветер` sounds almost fine, unlike `вольное дыхание`, which is ridiculous since breathing is a process not a human being.

Comment: `вольная продажа, по вольным ценам` is wrong. `свободная продажа, по свободным ценам` is only acceptable

Comment: You are right. My bad. I guess the logic here should be the same: selling as a process is a bit too far from an actor (human being) unlike behavior which is a direct attribute of a human controlled by his mind.

Answer (score 1):

`Вольный` is based on `воля` root which could be translated as `will` noun.

`Свободный` could be synonym has also another meaning `empty` related to space.

`Свобода` is about freedom.

`Воля` is rather about free will, but could be used as antonym to captivity too.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some addition to the previous answers. The words `свобода` and `воля` are pretty close to each to other and the use cases are depend, but saying generally:

- `свобода` is about freedom of choice, a potential state of thinking and acting freely.
- `воля` means `will`, it's more about a desired freedom (when someone who is not free wants to be free "хочет на волю" or "хочет быть на воле" or even "вызволен" - to be freed (by any means). Also it is about an inner state of mind and character of a person "У него есть сила воли (у него сильная воля), поэтому он легко бросил курить"

Comment: I would definitely add to your answer that "свобода" is very closely associated with the concept of "простор" or not being restricted in any way. Eg. *"Выступление в 19:00. Вход свободный"/"свободная одежда", "легко и свободно дышится"*. Here, "вход свободный" looks deceptively similar to "entry is free" but actually more bases off the idea "one can attend the performance, enter the venue however they want with no restrictions". Obviously, "воля" does not have this direct connection to wide, open space and with no physical or moral restrictions.